# Cannot convert System Object to String PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use the below PowerShell script

```
$get_AD_Server = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration).DnsDomain | Out-String
$get_Nearest_DC = (Get-ADDomainController -DomainName $get_AD_Server -Discover -NextClosestSite).Name
```

The output of `$get_AD_Server` contains contoso.com, however when I pass the variable `$get_AD_Server` in the next variable it always errors out. What am I doing wrong?

```
Get-ADDomainController : The format of the specified domain name is invalid
At line:2 char:20
+ ... arest_DC = (Get-ADDomainController -DomainName $get_AD_Server.ToStrin ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [Get-ADDomainController], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetADDomainController:BeginProcessingOverride:DiscoverDC:1212,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADDomainController
```

Comment: Remove `| Out-String` - the `DnsDomain` property is already a string

Comment: Hi Chris, Still the same it still says The format of the specified domain name is invalid.

Comment: try `(Get-ADDomain).DNSRoot`

Comment: Please be more precise with  your question, the message `$get_AD_Server.ToStrin ...` differs from the "*below powershell script*"  (which doesn't have a **`.ToString()`**). Anyways, try: `-DomainName "$get_AD_Server"` (also  Removing `| Out-String`).

Comment: Just use `$get_AD_Server = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration).where({$_.DNSDomain},'First').DNSDomain`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automatic variable unrolling will return a collection.

DNSDomain property may not be populated. In my case it isn't.  Assuming you've got that covered I think you might have better luck if you isolate the NIC configuration you care about.  If you narrow the return to 1 object `.DNSDomain` will be a string.

In my case this looks like:

```
(Get-WmiObject win32_NetworkAdapterCOnfiguration -Filter "IPEnabled = 'True'").DnsDomain
```

If needed just work on the filter until you find something that reliably only returns the NIC you care about.

Note: I may have misread something, but I worry you'll have an issue with the next step.  You may have trouble querying the AD domain when you aren't authenticated.  If you do hit something like that you may consider using the `-Credential` parameter on `Get-ADDomainController`.  Of course it'd be interactive at that point.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of fetching the DNS domain associated with the NIC, pull the computers domain from the `Win32_ComputerSystem` class:

```
$domain = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem).Domain
$nearestDC = (Get-ADDomainController -DomainName $domain -Discover -NextClosestSite).Name
```

Comment: Hi Mathias, This works perfectly on a Machine which is connected to a Domain, However i am trying to run this command from Windows PE, That is the reason why i am fetching this information from the NIC.

Comment: Does the correct domain name actually appear if you run `(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration).DnsDomain` in WinPE?

Comment: Yes it does both your query and mine has literally the same output.